# BigQuery - SQL convert string in Month DD, YYYY format to DATE

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I'd like to input a string in long month format ("December 31, 2020") and get out a DATE value.

I've tried `CAST(input_str as DATE)` and `CONVERT(DATE, input_str)` but neither do the trick. For CONVERT third argument, I see 107 as the shortened month style but can't find one for the lengthened month string.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: underlying database is MYSQL, querying via Google Cloud Platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expects the day to have two digits  if they have one or two digits you need to use `%e`

> ```
> SELECT STR_TO_DATE("December 31, 2020",'%M %d, %Y')
> ```
>
> ```
> | STR_TO_DATE("December 31, 2020",'%M %d, %Y') |
> | :------------------------------------------- |
> | 2020-12-31                                   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e0bf9f68d7e343d5affa4e4f3fe1c13)*

Try

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%B %e, %Y','December 31, 2020')
```

Comment: Thank you for this info, however it looks like I don't have access to STR_TO_DATE at the query layer ('Function not found'), I think I need a more generic approach

Comment: please try the new function

Comment: Thank you, this led me to solve with `PARSE_DATE("%B %e, %Y", 'December 31, 2020')`. I also updated question to be more specific to the query layer. Appreciate your help.